# Why does the C standard state that string literals shall begin and end in the initial shift state?

Tags: c, string-literals, c89

The ANSI X3.159-1989 "Programming Language C" standard states in the chapter "5.2.1.2 - Multibyte characters" that:

> For the source character set, the following shall hold:
>
> - A comment, string literal, character constant, or header name shall begin and end in the initial shift state.

1. Does it mean that a string literal or etc. shall begin and end with a character, represented by a value of the initial shift state, i.e. a single-byte value? Or does it mean that the environment shall reset it's current shift state to the initial shift state before and after processing a certain string literal or etc?
2. Why so? - I.e. what is the purpose to set the initial shift state, especially at the end of a string literal or etc?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the audience is the compiler creators.

Comment: It's about multi-byte characters. It's perfectly reasonable to expect a definition to begin and end with a whole, complete multi-byte sequence, and not start or end in the middle of a sequence.

Comment: It is a mis-wording. C99 says "For source *files*, the following shall hold", which does make a lot more sense (it is a requirement on source files). The original passage can be interpreted in a number of ways, which is bad.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. which would be typical of C/C++ standards.

Comment: The purpose of it as I see it is to make interpretation of program fragments unambiguous. By the way, "single-byte" does not entail "initial-shift-state" and vice versa.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., standard defines basic translation character set as *the set in which source files are written*, thus I don't see how it could me misinterpreted, although I agree that it's not suitable wording.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., no statement here declares that "single-byte does entail initial shift state", but does the opposite: "initial shift state entail single-byte interpretation of a values sequence"; as stated in C89: "While in the initial shift state, all single-byte characters retain their usual interpretation..."

Comment: I am talking about *fragments* of programs, not entire programs. A fragment that begins in an unknown shift state could mean anything.

Comment: No, "all single-byte characters retain their usual interpretation" does not mean that all bytes that can legally occur are single-byte characters (if that was the case, there would be no way to change from the initial shift state).

Comment: And people say that Unicode is complicated :-)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., it's somehow obvious for me that a source file can't begin with a multibyte character, as I see no keyword, operator, etc. that starts with that kind of character. But aren't we talking about multibyte characters that occur in a string literals, comments and etc? Otherwise I don't understand what is "fragment"

Comment: Unless you've got a very good reason, @CoSalamander, you should stop using the C89/C90 standard (which is over 30 years old and has been obsolete for more than 20 years) and use one of the 3 more recent standards — C99, C11 or C17 (preferably the latter, though the differences between C11 and C17 are fairly small, unlike the differences between C90 and C99 or between C99 and C11).

Comment: Whitespace characters can be multibyte (and are, in Unicode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the C standard state that string literals shall begin and end in the initial shift state?

Let's first see what exactly (or as exactly as the specification gets) is meant by "shift state":

> A multibyte character may have a *state-dependent encoding*, wherein
> each sequence of multibyte characters begins in an *initial shift state*
> and enters other implementation-defined *shift states* when specific
> multibyte characters are encountered in the sequence.  While in the
> initial shift state, all single-byte characters retain their usual
> interpretation and do not alter the shift state.  The interpretation
> for subsequent bytes in the sequence is a function of the current
> shift state.

Requiring string literals to begin and end in the initial shift state makes string semantics a lot simpler and more predictable.  If you concatenate two strings, or output them one after the other, you can be confident that their juxtaposition does not change the meaning of the latter.  If the first could terminate in a shift state different from the initial one then that would not be guaranteed.

The inherent assumption underlying all this is that language-level semantics are ignorant of the details of any particular character encoding.  They treat all strings as black boxes of bytes, terminated by a null character.

> 1. Does it mean that a string literal or etc. shall begin and end with a character, represented by a value of the initial shift state,
>    i.e. a single-byte value? Or does it mean that the environment shall
>    reset it's current shift state to the initial shift state before and
>    after processing a certain string literal or etc?

Neither.  With a state-dependent encoding, the current shift state is a running property of an interpretation of an encoded character sequence.  Characters do not necessarily encode shift states directly, but the encoding scheme provides a way to specify shift state changes.

Details can vary with the particular encoding scheme, but encoded characters, whether single- or multibyte, are not generally in a particular shift state inherently.  The whole point of such an encoding is that the same subsequence may be interpreted differently depending on the shift state.  Thus, starting in the initial shift state is an assertion about how multibyte character sequences will be interpreted, and only by implication a statement about what a string literal must contain.

Ending in the initial shift state, on the other hand, **is** a constraint on the contents of the string, *etc*.  A C source file is malformed if the bytes of a string literal *etc*. within, interpreted as starting in the initial shift state, encode one or more state shifts such that the shift state at the end of the byte sequence is different from the initial shift state.  This is exactly to relieve the implementation from having to be concerned with encoding issues, and absolutely not to require it to perform any kind of shift-state cleanup.

> 2. Why so? - I.e. what is the purpose to set the initial shift state, especially at the end of a string literal or etc?

It simplifies the language and improves the maintainability of C source files written in state-dependent source encodings.  Each unit that accepts user-defined free(ish) text is modular -- it has the same, well-defined meaning regardless of the surrounding context, and moving, copying, or deleting such units cannot change the lexical interpretation of the surrounding tokens.

Comment: It seems that I severely limited my understanding of the use of shift states, imagining that they only affect string literals and etc., but not imagining that their use could affect the interpretation of further code. As I think, this is what @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem referred to, speaking about fragments of a source files. Thank you for the extended answer.